# projectile-find-file and ivy - create file with subdirectories

Tags: projectile, ivy

I'm using ivy and projectile.

When I search for some file with projectile-find-file, and the file does not exist, I would it to be created.

If it is inside directories that also do not exist, ask if create those directories.

How to do that?

I found that some old code for helm https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3m8i5r/helmprojectile_quickly_findcreate_new_file_in/

and that it's already commited https://github.com/bbatsov/helm-projectile/commit/1f0dc42645f006e925718785b9abc6991b7ce2c4.

I have such function for `find-file`:

```el
(defun my-create-non-existent-directory ()
      (let ((parent-directory (file-name-directory buffer-file-name)))
        (when (and (not (file-exists-p parent-directory))
                   (y-or-n-p (format "Directory `%s' does not exist! Create it?" parent-directory)))
          (make-directory parent-directory t))
          ;; wait until directory is created
          (while (not (file-directory-p parent-directory))
              (sleep-for 1)))
          ;; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592095/how-do-i-create-an-empty-file-in-emacs/11990694#11990694
          (shell-command (concat "touch " (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name)))))

(add-to-list 'find-file-not-found-functions #'my-create-non-existent-directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like projectile-find-file will run my function.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Can you tell us why this is an answer? Thx.